# input range styling IE11/Firefox same as Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser

I have a range slider styled in Chrome.. I'm having major issues trying to get it to look the same in IE11 and firefox..  I've tried following some guides on how to make it compatible using the ms- and moz- for the webkit tags but it's still not formatting the same.  I understand it may be a little different but its just nowhere near the same result.  here's the code so far.. basically the range slider needs to be formatted same as the button above it.... any help much appreciated.

```css
.switch {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 100px;
 height: 30px;
 padding: 3px;
 margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
 border-radius: 18px;
 box-shadow: inset 0 -1px white, inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
 cursor: pointer;
 box-sizing:content-box;
}
.switch-input {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 box-sizing:content-box;
}
.switch-label {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 height: inherit;
 font-size: 10px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 background: #eceeef;
 border-radius: inherit;
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
 box-sizing:content-box;
}
.switch-label_1 {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 height: inherit;
 font-size: 10px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 background: #eceeef;
 border-radius: inherit;
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
 box-sizing:content-box;
}
.switch-label:before, .switch-label:after, .switch-label_1:before, .switch-label_1:after {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -.5em;
 line-height: 1;
 -webkit-transition: inherit;
 -moz-transition: inherit;
 -o-transition: inherit;
 transition: inherit;
 box-sizing:content-box;
}
.switch-label:before, .switch-label_1:before {
 content: attr(data-off);
 right: 11px;
 color: #aaaaaa;
 text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.switch-label:after, .switch-label_1:after {
 content: attr(data-on);
 left: 11px;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 opacity: 0;
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label {
 background: #86b692;
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label:before {
 opacity: 0;
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label:after {
 opacity: 1;
}

.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label_1 {
 background: #a9d2d5;
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label_1:before {
 opacity: 0;
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label_1:after {
 opacity: 1;
}

.switch-handle {
 position: absolute;
 top: 4px;
 left: 4px;
 width: 28px;
 height: 28px;
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
 border-radius: 100%;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.switch-handle:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin: -6px 0 0 -6px;
 width: 12px;
 height: 12px;
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
 border-radius: 6px;
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-handle {
 left: 74px;
 box-shadow: -1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
 
/* Transition
========================== */
.switch-label, .switch-label_1, .switch-handle {
 transition: All 0.3s ease;
 -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease;
 -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease;
 -o-transition: All 0.3s ease;
}

.range {
   display: block;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 300px;
 height: 30px;
 padding: 3px;
 margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
 border-radius: 18px;
 box-shadow: inset 0 -1px white, inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
 cursor: pointer;
 box-sizing:content-box;
}

.range-frame{
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 height: inherit;
 font-size: 10px;
 background: #eceeef;
 border-radius: inherit;
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
 box-sizing:content-box;
}



input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  background: lightgray;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 35px;
  width: 39px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  background: silver;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: lightgray;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  background: lightgray;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 35px;
  width: 39px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  background: silver;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 39px 0;
  color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: lightgray;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
  border-radius: 35px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
   border-radius: 35px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 35px;
  width: 39px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  background: silver;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: lightgray;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background:lightgray;
}


.output-value{
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  pointer-events: none;
  
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
 
  <title>Roland</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="range.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="switch.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <form>
   <label class="switch">
    <input class="switch-input" type="checkbox"  Filter="PL" Column="1">
    <span class="switch-label" data-on="PL" data-off="PL"></span> 
    <span class="switch-handle"></span> 
   </label>


   <label class="range">
    <span class="range-frame">
     <span for fader class="output-value" id="rangevalue">0 Nm</span>
     <input class="range-input" id="fader" type="range" min="0" max="150" step="1" value="0" onchange="outputUpdate(value)">
       </span>
   </label>
  </form>
  <script>
            function outputUpdate(vol) {
            document.getElementById('rangevalue').innerHTML=vol + ' Nm';
            }
        </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

here's what it should look like on all browsers -

thanks
C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input type range is quite customizable. Unfortunately, each browser has its own way and thus we have to write longer codes than expected. Than also you will not get the exact similar results. The result will look little bit different from other browsers.

You can refer an example below which I try to customize to make it looks like your range slider. I tested it with various browsers and it looks almost similar in most of the browsers.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  background: lightgray;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 35px;
  width: 39px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  background: silver;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: lightgray;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  background: lightgray;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 35px;
  width: 39px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  background: silver;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 39px 0;
  color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: lightgray;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
  border-radius: 35px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: lightgray;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
   border-radius: 35px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 35px;
  width: 39px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  background: silver;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: lightgray;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background:lightgray;
}

body {
  padding: 30px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<input type="range">


</body>
</html>
```

Output in various browsers:

[image]

Reference:

(1) [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/FtnAa)

(2) [Styling Cross-Browser Compatible Range Inputs with CSS](https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/)

Further, you can try to modify it based on your own requirement or use it as a reference for making the changes in your own code.

Comment: thanks for this.. I've updated my code but still cant get the slider to sit in the frame correctly and be transparent so the background shows with the text " Nm".  It requires to be formatted the same as the top switch

Comment: this is what it should look like on all browsers - <img src="http://wp1.cajsoft.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/capture.png">

Comment: As I already informed you, Every browser works in it's own way. So It will be very complex to get the similar appearance. If possible than you can try to keep the simple design so it will display with minimum difference across browsers.